# CQ5 - Sling currentPage in model class

Tags: java, aem, sling

In a CQ jsp it's easy to access the currentPage object by simply calling currentPage.getPath(). But I'm trying to remove any scrip lets and separate them out into a model class and can't figure out how to access the currentPage object. I thought I could do something like:

```
public void setResource(Resource resource){
    resource.getPath()
}
```

But that returns something like:

```
/content/home/subPage/jcr:content/banner
```

I'm just looking to return **/content/home/subPage/**.  I'm trying to use resources to get the path but can't find anything to do this. I know this must be something small that I'm just overlooking. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you are getting jcr:content/banner because you are calling the resource of a component inside a page, not the page itself.

to get the current page from a component you can use the PageManager:

> PageManager pageManager= resource.getResourceResolver().adaptTo(PageManager.class);
>
> Page currentPage = pageManager.getContainingPage(resource);